# DTD to XSD Converter for .Net Development

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, dtd

I'm trying to create a program which have conversion of a DTD to XSD format. Currently, I used [dtd2xsd.pl](http://www.w3.org/2000/04/schema_hack/) but the XSD.format result was not applicable to [DataSet.ReadXMLSchema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxmlschema(v=vs.110).aspx):

> dataSet.ReadXmlSchema(new StringReader(xmlSchemaString));

I encountered an error when I parsing a XSD format which have this schema attribute:

> xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema'

Here's the error message:

[image]

Anyone who knows a dtd2xsd converter - nugget, plugin or library that have ouput `http/www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` not `http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema`?

Comment: You have schema errors which means the data in your  xml isn't matching the schema website format.  You have to go to the website and determine what is wrong with the XML data.  Normally I use VS as a tool.  From the VS project menu : Add new Item : XML File.  Then paste your xml into the view.  Error will show up in the VS error list like any other syntax error.  You can click on Errors and the webpage for the schema will be added to your project.  The error indicates you are missing a namespace for a prefix you are using in the xml.